# Creating progressive filter with Mongodb ($or + $and)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I'm quite new in Mongodb. I am trying to create a filter which all its parameters will be optional but as the user passes them the result in mongodb will become more accurate

I thought this would work but unfortunately it doesn't:

```
const { name, lastName, country, jobRole } = req.query;
const user = await User.find({ $and: [
    { $or: [{ name }] },
    { $or: [{ lastName }] },
    { $or: [{ country }] },
    { $or: [{ jobRole }]}
], state: 'APPROVED' });
```

I would very much appreciate knowing how I can achieve the behavior of a progressive filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to build your query in JS rather than having complicated MongoDB query which interprets input parameters unnecessarly:

```js
let req = { query: { name: 1, country: 3 } };
const filters = ['name', 'lastName', 'country', 'jobRole'];
let progressive = [];

for (let filter of filters){
   let value = req.query[filter];
   if (value) {
      progressive.push({ [filter]: value })
   }
}

console.log(progressive);
```

```
const user = await User.find({ $and: [ { $or: progressive },  { state: 'APPROVED' } ] });
```

Comment: I just tried your code but I couldn't make it work. I am getting a 500 error on the server : (

Comment: Could you explain your code better so that I can integrate it with my project? : D

Comment: @MarkColling sorry for that, there was an error in your initial query. It should be fine. Basically this code just loops through your filter fields and adds more `$or` branches for those values that are defined in `req.query`

Comment: ERROR Error: Query filter must be an object, got an array

Comment: Try to take a look here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/XpKeHbvM_zI

Comment: I am playing with mongo playground, it works like what I said in my initial problem. But I do not understand why in node this is the code that I provided does not finish working.

Comment: Try to start with single condition - maybe you will be able to figure out what's wrong by adding subsequent subdocuments

Comment: It is already working but only takes the first value that is true, the progressive filter is not incremental. Maybe the node code you sent me, you need something else to make it work